# Trying to have two conditions for an if statement

Tags: python-3.6

Whenever I run this code, it always goes to the else statement. If the conditions for the signs being compatible are met, the output will always be not compatible. What am I doing wrong?
sign and sign2 are variables for zodiac signs. I am using zodiac sign elements to see if two signs are compatible with each other.

```
def zodiacCompatibility(sign, sign2):
fire = ["Aries, Leo, Sagittarius"]
earth = ["Capricorn, Taurus, Virgo"]
water = ["Pisces, Cancer, Scorpio"]
air = ["Gemini, Aquarius, Libra"]


if (sign in fire and sign2 in fire):
    result = ("The two signs are compatible")
if (sign in earth and sign2 in earth):
    result = ("The two signs are compatible")
if (sign in air and sign2 in air):
    result = ("The two signs are compatible")
if (sign in water and sign2 in water):
    result = ("The two signs are compatible")
if (sign in fire and sign2 in air):
    result = ("The two signs are compatible")
if (sign in water and sign2 in earth):
    result = ("The two signs are compatible")
if (sign in air and sign2 in fire):
    result = ("The two signs are compatible")
if (sign in earth and sign2 in water):
    result = ("The two signs are compatible")
else:
    result = ("The two signs are not compatible")

finalResult = zodiacCompatibility(sign, sign2)
```

print (finalResult)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
if (condition):
elif (condition):
elif (condition):
.
.
.
else:
```

What your code currently does is go through each if statement. If one or more of those conditions are satisfied it will write to `result` and then re-write over it again. The reason it goes to the `else statement` is because it is sign is not in earth and sign2 is not in water.

What I think you want is if none of the conditions are satisfied it goes to the else statement. This can be achieved to the structure I typed above.

[Here is more information][1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm) on how if statements and their counterparts work.

Comment: I decided to have one condition in the elif or if and nest an if inside of that. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But why didn't "and" work? Isn't "and" used if there are two conditions that need to be met.

Comment: "and" does work in the conditional, if both or either of the conditions are satisfied whatever is inside the statement gets executed.